# Nowhere-differentiable Lipschitz-continuous function

Tags: calculus, general-topology, big-list, lipschitz-functions

Does a function that fulfills the set of criteria stated in the title of the question exist? 
Actually, my question could be restated like this: Does Lipschitz continuity always imply differentiability almost everywhere?

Comment: It does, it’s rademacher’s theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem

Comment: Please re-open the question. There isn't anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It seem to contradict Rademacher's theorem, but actually it doesn't as you haven't put in all requirements for Rademacher's theorem in your criteria.

The Rademacher's theorem requires the domain (in which the function is Lipschitz) must be open (or have an open subset), if it fails that it doesn't have to be differentiable almost everywhere. Also if the set has measure zero then differentiability almost everywhere wouldn't imply differentiability anywhere anyway.

A trivial counter example would be the function $f:\{0\}\to\{0\}$ defined as $f(0)=0$. It's obviously Lipschitz, but nowhere differentiable. It however fails to fulfil the requirements of Rademacher's theorem.

Comment: When we speak of differentiability at a point, don't we require the point be in the function's domain _together_ with an open subset or a neighbourhood? Also, as far as I could see from the Wikipedia article, the theorem is stated for the Lebesgue-Borel measure, and having an open subset in the domain implies that the domain is of a positive measure.